# What is chmod 6050 good for

Tags: permissions, files, chmod

Recently I came across to command:

```
chmod -R 6050 /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/bin/container-executor
```

I don't know what that mean? I know file permissions like 777 etc. in a mode rwx for owner group others. But this results in

```
---Sr-s---. 1 root hadoop 36024 Oct 17 20:40 container-executor
```

Can someone please explain a bit?

Comment: These permissions are weird. 6550 would make more sense — it hardly ever makes sense to remove permissions from the owner but grant them to other users. Here the owner is root which effectively means the user permissions aren't used, it just looks strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `050` should be clear, that sets read and execute bits for the group 
the first `6` sets the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits (see `man 2 chmod`).
Effectively this means that executing `container-extractor` can only be done by `root` or members of the group `hadoop` and that the executable runs with effective `uid` being `root` and effective `gid` being `hadoop`.

Comment: It should be noted that `root` gets execute permission not because of the file owner permissions, but because it is superuser and at least one of the permission component (here group) has execute permission. 6110 permissions to my mind would have made more sense. It's common practice to deny read access to setuid/setgid commands (though the security benefit is very little)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for comments. Why did you delete your answer? I noticed it was there when I saved mine.